# React app with Cross-Origin Request Blocked to localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, cors, localhost

I'm new to both npm(and "siblings") and react. I still managed to create a user interface. My problem is to fetch data from my server, running on tomcat.

I get the following error message:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/CabinCTRLWS/webresources/service/clients. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Note that I try to access the localhost, http://127.0.0.1:8080/CabinCTRLWS/webresources/service/clients.
I also tried localhost and the actual IP address of the host.

FYI - it all runs on a virtual(KVM)machine - not that it should matter.

Pasting the address into firefox, chrome or Postman delivers the expected result.

```
[{"key":"cff3da01-a4ed-4304-9138-5c97398c9005","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0","mod":""}]
```

I'll later try to upload both the war for the server part and a zip for the react code.

I tried solutions from 3 different "tutorials".

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8
- https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html
- https://blog.logrocket.com/patterns-for-data-fetching-in-react-981ced7e5c56/

Still can not get it to work.

**What I want help with is to, from inside react code, call my service and in the end get a result I can loop over.**

code:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    alert("componentDidMount");
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/CabinCTRLWS/webresources/service/clients")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          clients: result.clients
        });
      },
      // Note: it's important to handle errors here
      // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
      // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
      }
    )
  }
```

I'm as I said, a complete noob when it comes to npm and react. My JS is kind of old-school.
I assume there are a lot of improvements and I welcome any comments but I most of all want to get by the CORS problem.

Comment: Check your server config, it should admit cross domain requests

Comment: @lissettdm. I haven't checkt the server config since it works in firefox, chrome and Postman. But I will make sure to add cors filter for tomcat. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The solution is to config your server. You won't get this error if you test the api with firefox, chrome and Postman.

Comment: @lissettdm - Thanks. I failed to get the conf right in tomcat at first try. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fix this with one of two ways

1. the easiest way is to add a proxy to your react app
   "proxy:"http://127.0.0.1:8080"

and then you request as follows:
fetch("/CabinCTRLWS/webresources/service/clients")

1. go to your server and allow cors by using the following npm package
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Back to me being a complete noob when it comes to npm and react..... installed the cors package but don't know how to use it. Is there a conf file? I found Local CORS Proxy and the problem is the same. How do I use it? Thanks for the reply. I'll have a look tomorrow.